# Show unselected vertices in UV/Image editor?

Tags: 3d-view, uv, vertices

Is there a way to show all vertices (even if they're unselected in the 3D view) in the UV editor?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's not like selecting everything is very laborious, you just press `a` in the 3D view (if you have something selected already press `a` twice).

Comment: It's because I want to be able to see the entire map while selecting only a few faces in the 3D view so I can see what's what.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Disable [*Sync Selection*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Layout_Editing#Selection_Modes) in the header toolbar of the *UV/Image Editor*.

Version 2.79:

[image]

Version 2.8+:

[image]

This stops the UVs only being visible if their corresponding vertices are selected. Now, even if no vertices are selected in the 3D view the UV image editor will still show them. If you do then select some vertices in the 3D view, the equivalent UVs will be selected in the image editor.
Geometry hidden in the view-port will be hidden in the UV editor too.

Comment: What if I don't want to see any wires or vertices in 3d view because I just want to see how end result looks like? I only managed to do that by switching to render display mode but it's updating too slow... Is there a way to edit UVs without entering edit mode at all? Or hide verts/edges?

Comment: Here is how to make a shortcut for this action: a) Press "Add New" button in User Preferences->Input "Image/UV Editor" (scroll down) and write "wm.context_toggle" instead of the word "none". b) Write "tool_settings.use_uv_select_sync" in the newly appeared "Context Attributes" field. c) Set ur shortcut in the respective field.

Comment: For Blender 2.8 : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/selecting-faces-on-object-from-uv-editor-window