# Selecting faces on object from UV editor window

Tags: modeling, texturing

I can't see this as an option so is there a way to select faces or islands and have them show up as selected faces on the object in 3D view.

In programs such as maya it is possible to work from either view and makes selection and mapping a little more user friendly.

I suspect it isn't possible in Blender but welcome your feed back.

***Edited** as flag as already answered, although the question was not asked in the other post in a way that showed in my search. 
I was looking for face and island selection to show in both views. The other asked about unselected vertices this obviously did not appear in the results.*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's a button you can check to sync edit mode mesh selection with the uv editor:

[image: Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync]

Enable it, then select a UV face in UV editor and see it selected in View3D!

It doesn't work however for UV islands, and as you enable it, the selection in the View3D takes precedence over the UV selection. That's for sure something to be improved.

**For Blender 2.8**

The button to toggle 'sync' is as shown below:
[image: 2.8 Update]

Comment: disagree that flushing the UV selection to mesh is necessarily an improvement, I can see you may want either behavior though - such details in how tools work aren't so simple to expose in a nice way.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, of course it should be possible in both directions, not View 3D -> UV Editor or the other way around only! I can only think of an enum with 3 items: off, UV > View3D and View3D > UV to specify the flushing direction.

Comment: Thanks @CodEmanX That is what I was looking for I had been trying to do it with island selection and was getting nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

(Blender 2.82)

I know this is years later, but I came across this so thought I'd give an update. I've been frustrated as to why it seems the UV map only shows when I select faces on the object itself. The other answers helped and so I just want to add how it solved my question, just in case anyone else needs it. Yes, you can select faces on the uv map and see the corresponding selected faces on the 3D Viewport [image: Select Faces UV Editor and See in 3D Viewport]

1) You may have to first select all the faces of the object and do a basic unwrap. I did various unwraps for this soda can model I have.

--- Select some faces on the object in "Edit Mode"...You don't have to select them all...And select that UV Sync button as, our the other fellow here mentioned (I circled it in red, upper left of picture). Then it should remain in the UV editor and allow you to select via the UV editor, as pictured.[image: Click UV Sync Selection]

You'll know if it works if the UV map should remain in the UV Editor even if you deselect the faces.[image: UV Layout In View]

Comment: This is an interesting workflow I will check it out. Been 6 years since I first posted this and I am recently back with Blender, so thanks all.

Comment: Haha yes this was my first post and a question I had needed an answer to as well. Pardon me bumping this topic, but I wanted to start getting experience, and I'm glad you had found help!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you are asking, but if you want to select UV islands in the mesh you can do this:

1. In the UV Editor choose `UVs > Seams From Islands`.
2. In the 3D view, in edit mode, you will see that the seams from the UVs are now showing on the object.
3. Staying in edit mode, hover anywhere on the model and press <kbd>L</kbd>, the UV island will now be selected (make sure that you are using face selection).

This helped me to make new objects from the UV islands (just press <kbd>P</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is what you need, there is an addon (space_view3d_moveUV.py) by kgeogeo to adjust the UV coordinates from the 3D view:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHN6_laY6JE&feature=youtu.be

download:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=282863&d=1389707684

and the blenderartists thread:

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256424-ADDON-Move-the-UV-from-the-3D-view