# Blender 2.82.7 unwrap problem - selected faces displaced and cannot place the image correctly

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

[image: selected unwrapped faces are displaced]cannot place the image correctly because selected unwrapped faces are displaced. I unwrapped UV > smart UV project. I added screenshots about my problem and can you understand that?. please help me...

the second image is my unwrapped one.

**the first image is the selected faces. but why I selected faces are not properly as the first image left panel. it like crashed. is it a model problem.?**
I tried to find properly select the faces around the bottle. On one occasion the proper faces were met. as the third screenshot.
But the look didn't come out the way I thought it would. 
because it applied to another face. It just didn't meet the expectations I was expecting. [image: final image unrapped]

[image: image cannot place corectly]

Comment: I don't really understand the question but maybe this will help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2782/86891

Comment: so on the second screenshot you've tried a second unwrap? It looks like it keeps the first UV map... Make sure, in the right panel > Object Data > UV maps, that the right UV map is chosen if you ever created a second one, also check your node organization to make sure the right UV map is used